# Ubuntu 10.04 breaks php5-ffmpeg and zend server

Tags: php5, ubuntu-10.04, zend-server

I would like to upgrade to 10.04, but there are a couple of packages that I use daily that Ubuntu says it will remove.

They are :
php5-ffmpeg,
zend server 5.0.2

There are many others in the list, but I use these two very frequently at work.

How can I manage to have the upgrade and these packages too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both zend and php5-ffmpeg are in universe, have you enabled the lucid universe repo for the upgrade?

Comment: how do i enable those repos ?

Comment: check /etc/apt/sources.list